# Вычислить процентное соотношение между двумя числами SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо сделать update этой таблице в поле ReviwedPer. В это поле надо внести процентное соотношение между столбцами CreateReqCount и reviewedreqCount
Пробовал сделать вот так

```
update #SalesTempReport
SET ReviewedPer = #SalesTempReport.CreateReqCount*#SalesTempReport.ReviewedReqCount/100
```

, но получаю стабильный результат 0. Тип данных столбца ReviewedPer float

Что я делаю не правильно? Если из update убрать деление на 100, то тогда все рассчитывается

Comment: делите на `100.0`, либо делайте `cast` к `float`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как не казалось бы странным, но даже оператор деления имеет [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). И вот относительно результата деления документация нам говорит нам следующее:

> Если целочисленный аргумент dividend делится на целочисленный аргумент divisor, то **результатом будет целое число, а дробная часть будет усечена**.

там же говорится про приоритет типов данных и неявное преобразование типов.

В данном вопросе вам следует явно определить 100 как вещественный тип, либо записав его в виде `100.0` либо явно изменив тип, например, `cast(100 as float)`.

Примеры:

```
SELECT 1/100
      ,1/100.0
      ,1/cast(100 as float)
```

Comment: Блин, вот совсем этот момент я не учел, по приоритет типов в операциях. Спасибо большое.